# makefile .o help... permission denied

Tags: makefile

I have the following makefile for my program. It creates program.o file, but when I try running it

```
./program.o
```

I get the following error:

```
./statsh.o: Permission denied.
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
HEADERS = statsh.h functions.h

default: statsh

statsh.o: statsh.c $(HEADERS)
    gcc -c statsh.c -o statsh.o

statsh: statsh.o
    gcc statsh.o -o statsh

clean:
    -rm -f statsh.o
    -rm -f statsh
```

Comment: You can't directly execute object files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.o` file is only a temporary product. It contains the machine code generated by the compiler for a single compilation unit (basically, a `.c` file here). However, that file is not intended to be executed -- and as you have already discovered, it cannot actually be executed.

The makefile produces the target file `statsh`. That's the one you want to execute. It contains the code from `statsh.o`, as well as library routines, etc. It is produced by your makefile by the rule

```
statsh: statsh.o
    gcc statsh.o -o statsh
```

which invokes GCC in order to have the linker/binder put the pieces together and construct the target program.